# Why does EF Core return entities not added to context when querying, but won't remove them when removed from context

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I am adding a field to my context. When I write a query that includes fields. It will include the field that was added to the context, but not saved. I haven't found any documentation that explains this behavior, so any that people are aware of would be appreciated. My next question is why/how can I make it so when I removed something from the context without committing the change to the database. That is isn't returned in queries.

The reason behind this is to allow easy roll backs if a calculation fails and I need to add back the removed entity.

Example code:

`f3` contains the newly added field

[image]

`f3` still contains the saved field even though it has been removed from the context, which seems unexpected compared to the add behavior. Should this be expected?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "fix" for fixing-up deleted entities when a formerly related entity begins to be tracked before the deletion is persisted to the DB was listed as a [breaking change for EF7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/breaking-changes?tabs=v7#deleted-fixup).  If you upgrade to EF7 you should no longer observe that behavior.

[Issue on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/28249)

Comment: Thanks, updating to EF7 resolved my issue. I had read that breaking change before and it didn't click until now.

Answer (score 2):

This might be worth raising with the EF Core team on Github (https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues)

I went and wrote a test to investigate this behavior in EF Core and confirmed it, then tried it in EF6 and it does behave differently, and more expectedly, removing the field from the farm when the farm is reloaded.

The behavior is consistent in both, but different when loading just fields by farm ID. For instance:

```
context.Add(field);
var f2 = context.Fields.Where(x=> x.FarmId == 12).ToList();
context.Remove(field);
var f3 = context.Fields.Where(x=> x.FarmId == 12).ToList();
```

In this case neither queries return the newly added field. I also tried it using `CreateProxy`

The issue looks to be about a difference in EF Core's tracking cache behavior. The tracking cache for Fields is being updated correctly, but the items being tracked by the Farm tracking cache are hanging onto references that have been marked as removed. For example:

```
int count = context.Fields.Local.Count; // 0
context.Add(field);
count = context.Fields.Local.Count; // 1
var f2 = context.Farm.Include(x=>x.Fields).Single(x=> x.FarmId == 12);
count = context.Fields.Local.Count; // 3 (If farm had 2 existing fields)
context.Remove(field);
count = context.Fields.Local.Count; // 2 (Field is removed from tracking cache as expected.)
var f3 = context.Farm.Include(x=>x.Fields).Single(x=> x.FarmId == 12);
```

Field is removed from the tracking cache, yet in EF Core retrieving the farm again from the Farm's tracking cache, it is still associated to the removed Field.

A solution to apply to correct the behaviour is to detach any existing tracked Farm before reloading it:

```
context.Add(field);
var f2 = context.Farm.Include(x=>x.Fields).Single(x=> x.FarmId == 12);
context.Remove(field);
context.Entry(f2).State = EntityState.Detached;
var f3 = context.Farm.Include(x=>x.Fields).Single(x=> x.FarmId == 12);
```

Now the removed field will not be reloaded when fetching the farm. As mentioned though, this does appear to be a bug in EF Core.

When it comes to calculations I would typically perform these in memory not using or relying on adding and removing entities through the operation/evaluation, but rather loading an initial state into memory, applying changes, then based on what the final desired state is, add/remove/update entities at the end.

Comment: I have edited the question a little bit, because I am unsure what the actual behavior is supposed to should be. I tried detaching the existing tracked farm and it still returns the removed field, which seems reasonable. It doesn't explain why it returns the newly added fields that haven't been saved though.

Comment: When you added the field, the context begins tracking that entity.  Fetching a Farm from the DbContext executes a query, but EF will populate any tracked Field references as part of populating that Farm, whether you use Include or not. If you ever want to load a farm (and fields) from the data state while ignoring any tracked instances, you can use `AsNoTracking()` in the query. This both does not add any loaded entities from the query into the tracking cache but also ignores any entities in the tracking cache.